# Write 2 columns in a csv file from an array

Tags: php, excel, csv

I'm trying to write in 2 differents columns in a csv file but everything I've found set all the values in the first column with a separator.

Here is a small modification of the script example on php.net

```
<?php
$list = array (
    ['City', 'Country'],
    ['Brussels', 'Belgium'],
    ['Paris', 'France'],
    ['Berlin', 'Germany']
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

[And here is my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHVcH.png) (I use Excel)

My question: is it possible to have the cities in A column and the countries in B column?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: You're talking about importing a csv in excel?

Comment: Yes I use excel 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your spreadsheet program that the columns are separated by commas.

You will probably get the option to nominate a delimiter on opening the file.

I think you also have an option on a column - something like "Text to columns"

Comment: Just looked on MS Excel and the text to columns option is under Data

Comment: Well the file you have output is text. CSV files are just textual representations of a 2D table. You just have to tell Excel how to open it. Other spreadsheets ask when opening the file.

Comment: PS If my answer was correct, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `fputcsv()` to use a different string as the delimiter instead of comma. This will use `TAB`, which is probably Excel's default:

```
fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t");
```